# Configuring a N:N relationship with a lookup of source entity type on target entity

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

I'm trying to configure an N:N relationship from `EntityA` to `EntityB`. On `EntityB`, I have a lookup field of type `EntityA`.

Now, when I go back to an entity of type `EntityA` (say, named `My Entity A`) and add an existing `EntityB` in the subgrid, the look up field on `EntityB` is updated with `My Entity A`. Which is clearly not what I want.

I simply want to be able to tie any number of `EntityB`'s to `EntityA` and I want `EntityB` to be able to point to any other `EntityA` on its look up field.

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a reference to entity A on Entity B then that is a N:1 relationship, not an N:N relationship.  Check that you don't have more than on relationship between the entities, and it is defined as a N:N.

Comment: OK. I've removed all relationships between EntityA and EntityB. Now I should define a new one as N:N from EntityA to EntityB, then add the lookup field (of type EntityA) on EntityB ?